# In what situation do we need to create an exception class that extends RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

We have a class A with two constructor parameters i and j. We can create an Object only when i < j. So :

1) Should I throw an exception, if someone tries to create object with i > j?

2) If yes, should I create a custom exception class?

3) If yes, it should extends Exception or RuntimeException class?

```
class A{
    int i;
    int j;
    public A(int i, int j) {
        // only when i < j we can create an object of A
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the idiomatic approach for that case would be to throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), which is a built-in runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom exception if you want to highlight the reason of the exception, put some information into the exception and catch the exception in the other place. Use checked(not Runtime) exception to force the user of your class to handle it.

In your case (as Robby proposed) IlligalArgumentExeption is a good choice.